# WSO2 ESB can not get response from rest API

Tags: xml, rest, soap, wso2-esb

I have a proxy that put data into parameters ({uri.var.parameter}) and Call a rest api for post parameters in that. The response for this api is like it:

```
<ResultSet count="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Result>
      <id>126</id>
      <contact_type>Individual</contact_type>
       .
       .
       .
</Result>
</ResultSet>
```

When I call this api with parameters in the soapui, I can see the above response, But when I call it by WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 I receive an error :
*First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found ResultSet*
My request was posted to the api but wso2 esb can not parse the response.
When I put property OUT_ONLY=true in synapse, my request went successfully but obviously I don't receive any response.
When I checked content_type in response header in SoapUI, it is :text/xml;charset=UTF8
I found [this  post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721106/wso2-esb-xml-response-in-wso2-rest-api-call-not-parsed) and added content_type:text/xml in both messageFomatter and messageBuilder in axis2 configure file, but I still receive same error.
Could you please provide me your sollution. Thanks

Comment: Try setting <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" />

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format of the endpoint to "pox".

```
<endpoint>
    <address format="pox" uri="http://www.example.com" />
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to use HTTP end point because I pass my parameters as URI template to api

Comment: You could also try setting `<property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2" />`